# Retrieving an Image from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello i want to get image from my sqlite database but i can't. Here mycodes:

```
public Bitmap ResmiAl(int dersID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from fotolar_table",null);
        if(c.moveToNext()){
            byte [] image = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("foto"));
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            //Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,2,image.length);
            return bitmap;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did `c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("foto"))` returned empty?

Comment: Using BLOBs is an anti-pattern. You'd better store the path to the image.